# Javascript Count how many garages have carmake1

Tags: javascript, object

I have an oject of data represented as garages.
I need to for example count the number of garages that have carmake1

I have tried this:

```
count = obj.garages.filter(function(item) { return item === "carmake1" }).length;
```

but this returns 0 and we know there are actual carmake1's in the data.

Here is the data:

```
obj = {
  "garages": [{
      "id": "1",
      "carId": "1",
      "tags": {
        "483": "carmake1",
        "485": "carmake3"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "carId": "1",
      "tags": {
        "483": "carmake1",
        "485": "carmake3"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "carId": "2",
      "tags": {
        "484": "carmake2",
        "485": "carmake3"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "carId": "2",
      "tags": {
        "483": "carmake1",
        "485": "carmake3"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "carId": "3",
      "tags": {
        "484": "carmake2",
        "485": "carmake3"
      }
    },
  ]
};
```

How can I get that?

Comment: has the wanted value alwas the same property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count it with the check of the property.

```js
var obj = obj = { "garages": [{ "id": "1", "carId": "1", "tags": { "483": "carmake1", "485": "carmake3" } }, { "id": "2", "carId": "1", "tags": { "483": "carmake1", "485": "carmake3" } }, { "id": "3", "carId": "2", "tags": { "484": "carmake2", "485": "carmake3" } }, { "id": "4", "carId": "2", "tags": { "483": "carmake1", "485": "carmake3" } }, { "id": "5", "carId": "3", "tags": { "484": "carmake2", "485": "carmake3" } }, ] },
    count = obj.garages.filter(function(item) {
        return item.tags[483] === "carmake1"
    }).length;

console.log(count);
```

Or check all properties in `tags`.

```js
var obj = obj = { "garages": [{ "id": "1", "carId": "1", "tags": { "483": "carmake1", "485": "carmake3" } }, { "id": "2", "carId": "1", "tags": { "483": "carmake1", "485": "carmake3" } }, { "id": "3", "carId": "2", "tags": { "484": "carmake2", "485": "carmake3" } }, { "id": "4", "carId": "2", "tags": { "483": "carmake1", "485": "carmake3" } }, { "id": "5", "carId": "3", "tags": { "484": "carmake2", "485": "carmake3" } }, ] },
    count = obj.garages.filter(function (item) {
        return Object.keys(item.tags).some(function (k) {
            return item.tags[k] === "carmake1"
        });
    }).length;

console.log(count);
```

Comment: One question : Why does this throws an error `if (objInput.garages[i].tags.483 == "carmake1")`. I get that the key is a number but does not understand the error with it.

Comment: it is a number and not a string. the keys of objects are strings and when in brackets, converted to string. maybe you have a look here [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Answer (score 0):

If the tag value is always 483 for carmake1, @Nina's solution would fit.

Otherwise maybe this will help.

```js
var obj = {
  "garages": [{
      "id": "1",
      "carId": "1",
      "tags": {
        "483": "carmake1",
        "485": "carmake3"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "carId": "1",
      "tags": {
        "483": "carmake1",
        "485": "carmake3"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "carId": "2",
      "tags": {
        "484": "carmake2",
        "485": "carmake3"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "carId": "2",
      "tags": {
        "483": "carmake1",
        "485": "carmake3"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "carId": "3",
      "tags": {
        "484": "carmake2",
        "485": "carmake3"
      }
    },
  ]
};

var found = obj.garages.filter(function(f) {
  var c = 0;
  Object.keys(f.tags).forEach(function(t) {
    if (f.tags[t] === 'carmake1') c++;
  });
  return c;
});

console.log(found.length);
```

Comment: where is Nina's solution anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Nina has the best answer, but for old browsers sake:

```js
console.clear();
obj = {
  'garages': [{
    'id': '1',
    'carId': '1',
    'tags': {
      '483': 'carmake1',
      '485': 'carmake3'
    }
  }, {
    'id': '2',
    'carId': '1',
    'tags': {
      '483': 'carmake1',
      '485': 'carmake3'
    }
  }, {
    'id': '3',
    'carId': '2',
    'tags': {
      '484': 'carmake2',
      '485': 'carmake3'
    }
  }, {
    'id': '4',
    'carId': '2',
    'tags': {
      '483': 'carmake1',
      '485': 'carmake3'
    }
  }, {
    'id': '5',
    'carId': '3',
    'tags': {
      '484': 'carmake2',
      '485': 'carmake3'
    }
  }, ]
};
var hascarmake1 = [];
for (var a = 0; a < obj.garages.length; a++) {
  var garage = obj.garages[a];
  for (var b in garage.tags) {
    var tag = garage.tags[b];
    if (tag == 'carmake1') {
      hascarmake1.push(garage);
      break;
    }
  }
}
console.log(hascarmake1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be?

```
var count = 0;
var input = '{"garages":[{"id":"1","carId":"1","tags":{"483":"carmake1","485":"carmake3"}},{"id":"2","carId":"1","tags":{"483":"carmake1","485":"carmake3"}},{"id":"3","carId":"2","tags":{"484":"carmake2","485":"carmake3"}},{"id":"4","carId":"2","tags":{"483":"carmake1","485":"carmake3"}},{"id":"5","carId":"3","tags":{"484":"carmake2","485":"carmake3"}}]}'

objInput = JSON.parse(input);

for (i in objInput.garages) {
  if (objInput.garages[i].tags[483] == "carmake1") {
    count++;
  }
}

console.log(count);
```

[Check the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7v69rad3/2/)