# Javascript loop to count each specified field and count totals of each

Tags: javascript, object

I am using the following code when filters a specified carmake and counts how many there are.

Here is the data and code:

```
var obj = obj = { 
    "garages": [{ 
        "id": "1", 
        "carId": "1", 
        "tags": { 
            "483": "carmake1", 
            "485": "carmake3" 
        } 
    }, 
    { 
        "id": "2", 
        "carId": "1", 
        "tags": { 
            "483": "carmake1", 
            "485": "carmake3" 
        } 
    }, 
    { 
        "id": "3", 
        "carId": "2", 
        "tags": { 
            "484": "carmake2", 
            "485": "carmake3" 
        } 
    }, 
    { 
        "id": "4", 
        "carId": "2", 
        "tags": { 
            "483": "carmake1", 
            "485": "carmake3" 
        } 
    }, 
    { 
        "id": "5", 
        "carId": "3", 
        "tags": { 
            "484": "carmake2", 
            "485": "carmake3" 
        } 
    }, 
] 
};

    count = obj.garages.filter(function(item) {
        return item.tags[483] === "carmake1"
    }).length;

    console.log(count);
```

What I need to do it to create a loop that will basically check all tags and count how many there are of each.

I know how to manually specify each but how can I do this automatically so that it will just scan the tags and count them ?

The final result I'd like the have is to end up with an array containing all the totals.

Comment: `obj = obj = {`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Count how many garages have carmake1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107350/javascript-count-how-many-garages-have-carmake1)

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen Wow. It's almost like OP's asking a separate question for each task he needs to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count manually instead of filter:

```js
var obj={garages:[{id:"1",carId:"1",tags:{483:"carmake1",485:"carmake3"}},{id:"2",carId:"1",tags:{483:"carmake1",485:"carmake3"}},{id:"3",carId:"2",tags:{484:"carmake2",485:"carmake3"}},{id:"4",carId:"2",tags:{483:"carmake1",485:"carmake3"}},{id:"5",carId:"3",tags:{484:"carmake2",485:"carmake3"}}]};

var r = {};

obj.garages.forEach(function(o) {
  for (var t in o.tags) {
    r[t] = (r[t] || 0) + 1
  }
})

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, you need to iterate the array and count the propertie keys

```
var response = [];
obj.garages.forEach(function(item) {
    response.push(Object.keys(item.tags).length);  
});
```

Check this fiddle out https://jsfiddle.net/bvccedoo/